# Does "you" in the sentence "I didn't know you could do that" actually mean the person you're speaking to, or an arbitrary person?

Tags: meaning

I was asked this by my ESL friend and didn't know how to answer because I had never really thought about it. I always thought of the "you" in the sentence (and similar sentences) to mean an arbitrary person, including but not necessarily restricted to the person you're speaking to.

Comment: It depends on context.  If a friend approaches you and starts juggling then it refers to that friend.  If the friend is talking about seeing people bungee-jumping off your town's tallest skyscraper, "you" means "anyone".

Comment: Without more context, it could mean either.  For example, if your friend had just done a somersault, you might mean that you didn't know that s/he could do somersaults.  But, if your friend had just suggested visiting a particular building, you might me that you didn't know that people in general are allowed to visit it.

Comment: What's an "ESL friend"?

Comment: @TrevorD that would be a friend who speaks English as a Second Language.

Comment: @Hellion - Or "Electronics Sports League".  (Probably not "Equivalent Series Inductance".)

Comment: Generic you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s just the more modern way of saying ‘one’, as in ‘I didn’t know one [any given person] could do that.’